# D3 Typeerror cannot read property of undefined

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to follow this guide, but implementing my own data:

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/stackedarea_basic.html

Here is my function

```
getStackedAreaChart: function(pod) {
      //eval is sligtly heavily used here.
      var cssName = ".stackedareachart-" + pod;
      var podData = eval("this.StackedAreaChartData" + pod);
      var ListName = eval("this.List" + pod);
      // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
      var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 },
        width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // append the svg object to the body of the page
      var svg = d3
        .select(cssName)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var sumstat = d3
        .nest()
        .key(function(d) {
          return d.time;
        })
        .entries(podData);
      console.log(sumstat);
      // Stack the data: each group will be represented on top of each other
      var mygroups = ListName; // list of group names
      var mygroup = []; // list of group names
      for (let i = 1; i <= mygroups.length; i++) {
        mygroup.push(i);
      }
      console.log(mygroups);
      console.log(mygroup);
      var stackedData = d3
        .stack()
        .keys(mygroup)
        .value(function(d, key) {
          return d.values[key].interactionCount;
        })(sumstat);

      // Add X axis --> it is a date format
      var x = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain(
          d3.extent(podData, function(d) {
            return d.time;
          })
        )
        .range([0, width]);
      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));

      // Add Y axis
      var y = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([
          0,
          d3.max(podData, function(d) {
            return +d.interactionCount;
          })
        ])
        .range([height, 0]);
      svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));

      // color palette
      var color = d3
        .scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(mygroups)
        .range([
          "#e41a1c",
          "#377eb8",
          "#4daf4a",
          "#984ea3",
          "#ff7f00",
          "#ffff33",
          "#a65628",
          "#f781bf",
          "#999999"
        ]);

      // Show the areas
      svg
        .selectAll("mylayers")
        .data(stackedData)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          name = mygroups[d.key - 1];
          return color(name);
        })
        .attr(
          "d",
          d3
            .area()
            .x(function(d, i) {
              return x(d.data.key);
            })
            .y0(function(d) {
              return y(d[0]);
            })
            .y1(function(d) {
              return y(d[1]);
            })
        );
    }
  }
```

Here is where I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'interactionCount' of undefined

  var stackedData = d3
    .stack()
    .keys(mygroups)
    .value(function(d, key) {
      return d.values[key].interactionCount;
    })(sumstat);
```

For some reason if I make the list mygroup have one less element in the array, I don't get this error. BUT, my chart doesn't come out looking right.

I've followed the guide word for word line by line and I have no problems replicating the chart. But, when using my own data, I run into issues. Here is the json data:

```
[{"interactionCount":0,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C1"},{"interactionCount":6,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C2"},{"interactionCount":0,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C3"},{"interactionCount":14,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C4"},{"interactionCount":44,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C5"},{"interactionCount":0,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C6"},{"interactionCount":8,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C7"},{"interactionCount":0,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C8"},{"interactionCount":5,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C9"},{"interactionCount":2,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C10"},{"interactionCount":0,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C11"},{"interactionCount":13,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C12"},{"interactionCount":6,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C13"},{"interactionCount":0,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C14"},{"interactionCount":6,"time":951,"pod":"POD2","client":"C15"}]
```

I was thinking maybe the error was when interactionCount was 0. This is not a problem. I did test this out.

Although I'm following the guide line by line. What am I doing wrong to receive the error?

NOTE my data is json data. The user uses CSV data. Could this be my problem?

Comment: The tutorial passes in mygroup, not mygroups in stackedData.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I thought the tutorial was making a mistake so that's why I used mygroups instead. I converted it back to mygroup in the example up above.